# Why doesn't property syntax work when dynamically adding TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, dynamic, properties, runtime

I'm trying to learn how to add WPF controls at runtime. Below is a simple example with question to follow:

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="BindAndDynamicPractice.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel Name="splMain">
        <Button Name="btnAddMore" Click="btnAddMore_Click">Add Another</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

C#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Shapes;


namespace BindAndDynamicPractice
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void btnAddMore_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            AnotherTextBox mybindingtest = new AnotherTextBox();
            splMain.Children.Add(mybindingtest.PropTextBox);
        }
    }

    public class AnotherTextBox
    {
        System.Windows.Controls.TextBox _newTextBox = new TextBox();
        public TextBox PropTextBox { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This compiles but I get a runtime error which I think has something to do with attempting to use a property. I believe this because when I change the AnotherTextBox class to the following:

```
public class AnotherTextBox
   {
       System.Windows.Controls.TextBox _newTextBox = new TextBox();

       public TextBox PropTextBox()
       {
           return _newTextBox;
       }
    }
```

And then update btnAddMore_Click:

```
public void btnAddMore_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            AnotherTextBox mybindingtest = new AnotherTextBox();
            splMain.Children.Add(mybindingtest.PropTextBox());
        }
```

Now this works as it should.

So why does using a full get method work but using a property not?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have a property, you have a method. Therefore you must call it using method syntax. Are you by chance coming from Java?

A method:

```
public TextBox PropTextBox()
{
   return _newTextBox;
}
```

A property:

```
public TextBox PropTextBox {
    get { return _newTextBox(); }
}
```

There is a tutorial on properties here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288470(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Thanks, don't know Java. I now see my error in trying to use automatic property without tying it to the underlying private field.